# Linked List Destructor - I have looked at previous posts. Still having problems :(

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

This is my declaration of the linked list:

```
// linked list of links
struct LinkedNode {
    Linked data;
    LinkedNode* next;

LinkedNode (const Linked& link); //ignore, not a concern at them moment
};

LinkedNode* firstLink;
LinkedNode* lastLink;
```

This is my destructor implementation:

```
Portion::~Portion(){
while(firstLink != NULL){
    LinkedNode *temp = firstLink;
    firstLink = firstLink->next;
    delete temp;
}
lastLink = NULL;
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting a segmentation fault. I have tried to delete lastLink and firstLink and then individually. I have done the same but setting them NULL, as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in what little code you posted.

Comment: Could you post enough code to demonstrate the problem (preferably as a complete, self-contained test case)? There's nothing obviously wrong with the snippet you've posted, so the problem is probably in the code you haven't posted.

Comment: Try to create a minimal example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Doing so might already tell you where the problem is.

Comment: Just because the crash happens in the destructor does not mean that there's something wrong with the destructor itself. Actually, it looks fine. The problem is elsewhere. There could be hundreds of different reasons this can crash, but there's no way to tell from what you posted. For starters, it would be a good idea to tell us which specific line crashes.

Comment: What's in destructor of Linked ?

Comment: `//ignore, not a concern at them moment`  How do you know this?  A badly written copy constructor can corrupt a program just as easily as any other code.

Comment: The copy constructor was given. I thought I was still doing something wrong with the destructor because the program ran fine until I implemented the destructor. I will look into other issues. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the destructor that is the problem. I was just convinced so. I will look back on the rest of my program.